# How to set docker image version in micronaut?

Tags: docker, micronaut

I use micronaut 3.8.4 to build my project and build docker image with below commands:

```
./gradlew assemble
./gradlew dockerBuild
```

and a image "foo:latest" is added into docker.

My question is, how to set the docker image foo's version? For example, I want to set the docker image foo's version to the same version in build.gradle, so that when I see images in docker, it will show `foo:1.0`

```
plugins {
    id("groovy")
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "3.7.0"
    id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") version "2.8.0"
}

version = "1.0"
group = "com.myfoo"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just figured it out.

In build.gradle, add below block

```
dockerBuild {
    images = ["foo:$project.version"]
}
```